# Allow user auto posting from Meteor app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm setting up a service that allows users to post photos. I want to allow for users to set up scheduled posts. I'm not sure how Facebook and Tumblr accomplish this feat. Could someone point me in the right direction of thought. One solution i've come up with is create a queueing system with a mongo collection. User a  TTL index along with a meteor hook to upload those posts. Not sure if this is the right way. I also may want to send those posts to Facebook as well. Any suggestions?